# JavaScript: Computer guesses my number game, cannot repeat incorrectly guessed number

Tags: javascript, loops

Looking for some feedback.

I am very new to programming. And having a go at the following challenge for the past few days:
A user inputs a number 0-5 (howmany fingers am I holding up?), and the computer randomly guesses what the number is and howmany tries it took to guess it. I managed to write a code that executed this, however it sometimes took the computer 20+ tries. I figured it should only take a maximum of 6 tries, as there are only 6 numbers.

```
document.getElementById("submitButton").onclick = function() {

    var chosenNumber = document.getElementById("myNumber").value;
    var gotIt = false;
    var howManyGuesses = 0;
    var cmpGuess = 0;
    var temp = "";
    var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    var ranNums = [];
    i = numbers.length

    console.log(numbers);
    console.log(ranNums);

    if (chosenNumber < 0 || chosenNumber > 5) {
        alert("Please choose a number between 0 and 5.")
        return;
    }

    while (gotIt == false) {

        cmpGuess = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));


        howManyGuesses = howManyGuesses + 1;



        if (cmpGuess == chosenNumber) {
            gotIt = true;
            alert("Got it! You number was " + chosenNumber + " and it took me " + howManyGuesses + " guesses to get it!")
        } else {
            numbers.splice(cmpGuess, 1);
            ranNums.push(cmpGuess);
            i--;
        }

    }


}
```

I have just been messing around with information received online, and am not sure if the splice and push are working correctly. Before I added the i-- at the end, it seemed that it still took the computer many tries. I added it, and now it always seems to be 6 or less, but my browser is constantly crashing.

Could anyone look at this code an maybe give me some feedback?

Thank you very much!

Comment: _"6 tries, as there are only 6 numbers"_ There is a 1 in 6 chance to guess the correct answer, but that does not mean a guess ___will___ be correct within 6 tries.

Comment: Hey Patrick, thank you for your response. What I meant to say was that I basically want the computer to make a decision as a human would. E.g. - You are holding 3 fingers behind your back, and you keep the same amount of fingers up while I make a guess. I guess that you are holding up 2 fingers, which is incorrect. Then I would not want to guess the number 2 again, as I already know it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is flawed. The code picks a random number between 0 and `i + 1`, and if it doesn't guess correctly then decrease `i--` (and use splice on `numbers`, but the array is never used in the loop again, so it's useless).

Let's imaging that for the first iteration it picks `2`. It's between the range, so it's okay. But it's not the correct one – the user put `5` in the input box – so it decrease `i` by one. At the next iteration then, it might picks *again* `2` since it's still in the current range.

Instead of considering `cmpGuess` as the guessed number, you should consider it as the *guessed index*. So you can remove the index that doesn't contain the guessed number, removing the wrong number from the pool you're picking up.

And you were close to that, you basically needs to change:

```
if (cmpGuess == chosenNumber) {
```

to:

```
if (numbers[cmpGuess] == chosenNumber) {
```

At this point your code should works (however, I'm not sure `ranNums.push(cmpGuess);` what is used for).

Comment: Hey ZER0, thank you! Took me a while to figure it out, but this comment specifically  helped to make everything crystal clear.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this approach to find the number. Comments in the code:

```js
//The variables you are given in the problem:
const choosen = 2;
const min = 0;
const max = 5;

//A function to simluate "computer guessing"
const guess = (min, max, target) => {
  //Iterate every value between min - max, incrementing i by 1 each time
  for (let i = min; i <= max; i += 1) {
    //Check if the value at the current index is the value we're looking for
    if (i === target) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  //If iterate all values between min - max and target isnt found, return null to indicate that
  return null;
}

const numberGuesses = guess(min, max, choosen);

//Function to generate little message based on results of guess()
const message = numberGuesses => Boolean(numberGuesses) ? `${choosen} found in ${numberGuesses} guesses` : `Couldn\'t find ${choosen}`;
console.log(message(numberGuesses));
```